# Fit an Object containing an SVG to a DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm trying to fit the object to the div. I tried the solutions for fitting an image, but they didn't work in this case. Any thoughts?

HTML:

```html
<div class="image">
  <object id="tangramObj" class="tangram" data="" type="image/svg+xml">
    <svg version="1.1"
         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
         xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="606" height="202"
         baseProfile="full">...</svg>
  </object>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.image {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20%;
  left: 20%;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
}

.tangram {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SVG path is bigger than the svg container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67006769/svg-path-is-bigger-than-the-svg-container)

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correct you question You define the width="606" height="202" in your SVG and  100% in your CSS.

try

```
    <div class="image">
    <object id="tangramObj" class="tangram" data="" type="image/svg+xml">
        <svg version="1.1"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
            xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
            baseProfile="full">
        </svg>
    </object>
</div>
```

Comment: hello thanks, but it still doesn't work. The size of my svg is still the same and it gets cropped instead. Is there any other way?